# How to replace a TDBNavigator with a TSpeedButton?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I did:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataTable.qOrders.Next;
end;
```

It works, but the problem is when I click the button to reach the last record, the button is not disabled, like in a `TDBNavigator`.

How did I make the `TSpeedButton` disable and enable automatically like the `TDBNavigator` does?

Comment: Just disable the button next event in your button last event

Answer (score 8):

Drop a `TActionList` onto your form and add the *standard* dataset actions to it. Connect these actions to your dataset and your speedbuttons to the appropriate actions. These standard actions will handle the *enable state* according to the current dataset state.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution, that works perfectly for me.

I have a form (frmMain), dataset (dsWork), datasource (srcWork), grid and two speedbuttons (btnNext and btnPrior). The important part is in "OnDataChange" event of TDataSource. Here is the source code:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Grids, DBGrids, DB, DBTables, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    btnNext: TButton;
    srcWork: TDataSource;
    dsWork: TTable;
    btnPrior: TButton;
    grdWork: TDBGrid;
    procedure btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure srcWorkDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if not dsWork.Eof then dsWork.Next;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnPriorClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if not dsWork.Bof then dsWork.Prior;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.srcWorkDataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
   btnNext.Enabled := not dsWork.Eof;
   btnPrior.Enabled := not dsWork.Bof;
end;

end.
```